# Какими членами предложения являются?

Tags: члены-предложения

Падают листья на землю и на Кота.
(Ю.Коваль)
На землю - обстоятельство, выраженное существительным с предлогом. А "на Кота"? Это дополнение (на кого?) Или все-таки обстоятельство, потому что спрашиваем "куда" и ответ - на кота.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**["Осеннее котяро", Юрий Коваль](https://kniga-online.com/books/detskaya-literarura/prochaja-detskaja-literatura/page-16-337799-alyi-i-drugie-rasskazy-yurii-iosifovich-koval.html)**

```
    Падают листья на землю и на кота. А кот караулит, 
    подстерегает и вдруг бросается на падающий лист, 
    прихлопывает его лапой и грозно грызёт. Ему кажется, что 
    это такие воробьи разноцветные.

   «Глупое осеннее котяро, — думаю я. — Листья с воробьями 
    путает». А кот заметил, что я про него думаю, и 
    затаился.
```

*Падают листья **на землю и на кота.***

1. Падежная форма существительного в общем случае может быть **дополнением, обстоятельством, несогласованным определением.**
2. **И дополнение, и обстоятельство** характеризуют действие, но по-разному. Дополнение называет **объект,** на который распространяется действие (дополняет содержание самого действия), а обстоятельство или качественно характеризует действие (как?), или определяет **внешнюю характеристику** действия (где? **куда?** откуда? когда? и т.д.).
3. Надо сделать **выбор**: (на кого/что?) или (куда?).

Объект может быть **дополнением** (на кого/что), но может и обозначать **направление** падения (вниз).

4. Выбираем (на кого/что), то есть на предметы/объекты, а не вниз. Отношения однородные: это **дополнение** в обоих случаях.

Объект **дополняет действие,** так что мы можем понять значение глагола и подобрать его по толковому словарю: листья срываются и падают: на землю, на кота и вообще на все. **Главное — на кота, он здесь в качестве объекта.** Но  тогда и земля будет тоже объектом.

5. **Сравнить:** ...клест полетел к окну. Он ударился головой о стекло и, ошеломленный, упал **вниз, на крышу клетки.** Здесь второе **обстоятельство** уточняет первое. То есть объект  (***на крышу клетки***)  задает направление (куда именно?).
6. Важно учитывать тот естественный вопрос, который мы задаем: **куда или на кого?** Листья падают (куда?) вниз, на землю.  Листья падают (на кого?) на кота.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

(1) **Словарь**

**ПАДАТЬ,** -аю, -аешь; падающий; нсв. 1. (св. упасть; устар. пасть). Валиться **вниз на землю** под действием собственной тяжести (обычно от спелости, ветхости, гниения и т.п.). **Листья, яблоки, орехи и т.п. падают.**

(2) **[Учебник для педвузов](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf):** Кустова Г.А. **"Синтаксис современного русского языка**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (стр. 80) — это второстепенный член предложения, называющий лицо, предмет или явление, на который **распространяется действие** или по отношению к которому проявляется признак.

Морфологизованным способом выражения дополнения являются формы **косвенных падежей существительных**, поскольку косвенный падеж является **показателем зависимости** существительного от другого слова: читать книгу, любоваться закатом.

Дополнения могут иметь **добавочные обстоятельственные** значения: познакомились (встретились, провели отпуск) у друзей
(у кого? и где?).

**Косвенное дополнение** выражается формами косвенных падежей без предлогов и с предлогами (в том числе В. п. с предлогом).
Дополнение может относиться **к глаголу** (изучать математику, надеяться на помощь), к существительному (строительство
школы, соблюдение правил, занятия спортом, обращение к врачу,
воспоминание о лете), **к прилагательному** (похожий на отца, отличный от других, верный слову, внимательный к детям), к **сравнительной** степени прилагательного или наречия (дом выше дерева, самолет летел выше облаков), **к наречию** (назло врагу).

**ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВО** (стр. 81) — это второстепенный член предложения, который относится **к слову со значением действия** или признака и обозначает качественные и количественные характеристики этого действия или признака (способ осуществления действия, степень интенсивности действия или проявления признака), а также **различные внешние обстоятельства осуществления действия** (время, причину, условие и т.д.).

**ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ** (стр. 77) — это второстепенный член предложения, который отвечает на вопросы какой? , который? , чей?, относится
к слову **с предметным значением** (обычно **существительному**) и обозначает **признак**.

По характеру связи определения с определяемым словом и способу выражения **различаются** согласованные определения, несогласованные определения и приложения. **Несогласованные определения** выражаются: 1) **существительным в косвенном падеже с предлогом и без предлога:** рекомендация врача, член комиссии, состав президиума, жители Москвы, крыша дома, костюм в полоску, книжка с картинками, чашка без ручки, ткань на костюм;

У **несогласованных** определений значение признака дополняется и осложняется **другими значениями** (во многих случаях дополнительное значение можно установить по той конструкции, с
которой соотносится определение). Это могут быть **значения:**

1. **Субъекта или носителя признака**: возвращение героя (герой
   вернулся); синева неба (небо синее); 2) **принадлежности**: меч героя, пиджак отца (меч принадлежит герою, у героя есть меч; пиджак принадлежит отцу, отцовский пиджак)', 3) **целого**: ножка стула (ножка — часть стула); **и т.д**.

Добавочными могут быть также **обстоятельственные значения:**
6) места: дома на горе / за рекой (сравним: дома находятся на
горе за рекой).

Comment: промахнулся с вопросом как похоже)

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо огромное за подробный ответ. Можно уточню? Верно ли я поняла, что "на землю" и "на кота" будет дополнением, если выберу вопросы "на что?" (на землю) и "на кого?" (на кота). Также не будет ошибкой, если обозначу и обстоятельствами "куда?"(вниз на землю) и "куда?" (вниз на кота).

Comment: Ой, отправилось раньше времени. Подытожу свой вопрос, какой из 3 вариантов правильный: 1 - это 2 однородных дополнения, 2 - это 2 однородных обстоятельства, 3 - это обстоятельство (на землю) и дополнение (на Кота)?

Comment: Здесь однородные  отношения (союз И), поэтому члены предложения должны быть одинаковые. А вдруг не должны?  Что если это худ. прием? Надо искать компромисс. По семантике они падают вниз и при этом попадают на кота. Пусть основное решение будет в пользу направления,  а объектное значение  будет дополнительным: куда? вниз  и на кого? на кота.  Еще вариант: на кота можно считать дополнением с добавочным обстоятельственным значением.

Comment: Спасибо большое, почему-то не сразу увидела ваш ответ

Comment: Можно ли я ещё раз уточню..Могу ли я принять эти 2 слова как дополнения. Как я поняла могу. Будет ли это более правильным, чем принять их за обстоятельства. Или все же равноценны оба варианта?

Comment: Пусть это будут дополнения с  добавочным обст. значением.  Такой вариант  соответствует однородным отношениям.

Comment: Как здорово, что есть возможность получить ответы от знающих людей!

Comment: Мария, спасибо за оценку.  Форум действительно один из лучших, люди активные, заинтересованные, с хорошими знаниями. Так что приходите, задавайте интересные вопросы, отвечайте сами)